# How is it possible that SQL query and ActiveRecord.find_by_sql return different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a conundrum. I am writing a scope on my `Account` class that finds a bunch of account objects that meet a lengthy condition. Here is my scope:

```
 scope :unverified_with_no_associations, -> {
  find_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(accounts.id, accounts.email)) FROM accounts WHERE level = 0 AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM verifications) AND id NOT IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM positions) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM edits) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM posts) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM reviews) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(sender_id) FROM kudos) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM stacks WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL)")
}
```

When I execute this scope by with `Account.unverified_with_no_associations` I receive this object back `[#<Account:0x007f7fc94d79c0 id: nil>]`.

However when I connect to the database and execute the sql as is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(accounts.id, accounts.email)) FROM accounts WHERE level = 0 AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM verifications) AND id NOT IN 
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM positions) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM edits) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM posts) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM reviews) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(sender_id) FROM kudos) AND id NOT IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM stacks WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL);
```

I receive the number `221214`. Why would it be that I get to differenct results? I've ruled out the possibility of connecting onto different databases. I've checked my `.env` files and have confirmed that I am in the same database as my application. Does anyone know why I would get such a difference in queries?

------------UPDATE--------

I discovered that `find_by_sql` does not like the inclusion of `COUNT` in its argument. When I remove the `COUNT()` from the sql and later execute a `.count` method I retrieve the matching number.

However, I still get different results when I use both methods.

What I really need are distinct `accounts.id` and `accounts.email` but the methods do not return the same output.

For example, when I execute the sql version I receive an output that looks like this:

```
row
---------
(1234,me@gmail.com)
```

but when I use the activerecord version I get this:

```
[#<Account:0x007fdc9ec104d0 id: nil>]
```

but with no accompanying email.

----UPDATE #3------

Also on my sql output I get this `unknown OID 2249: failed to recognize type of 'row'. It will be treated as String.` What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have right result in both examples.

If you use only `count` in select you always got a number as result of query. So your result from database is expectable.

In rails case you trying to get some set of records by `scope` with `count` in select statement. It's expectable to got empty set if you have `count` in your query.

Try `count_by_sql` method http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/count_by_sql/class
to get number of records instead of empty set.

And use it without scope, but with class method:

```
def self.unverified_with_no_associations()
  self.count_by_sql("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(accounts.id, accounts.email)) FROM accounts WHERE level = 0 AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM verifications) AND id NOT IN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM positions) AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM edits) AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM posts) AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM reviews) AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(sender_id) FROM kudos) AND id NOT IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT(account_id) FROM stacks WHERE account_id IS NOT NULL)")
end
```

Comment: rootatdarkstar, thanks for your reply. I didn't know there was a `count_by_sql` method. Would you know about the problem which I specified on my update. I still don't get matching records.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct and open a new question. Thanks for your help with the `count_by_sql`.

Comment: Thanks rootatdarkstar. I'll try your recommendation. I posted another question found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817143/a-situation-where-activerecord-and-sql-do-not-return-the-same-results-due-to-unk if you feel like getting more points today.

Comment: You have `count_by_sql...WHERE level = 0...`. How would you use prepared parameters for this?